# Javascript validation highlight field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple JS validation for my form. I need it to highlight red onblur when not filled out, and green once you fill it in afterwards. Sorry, not allowed to imbed images in my posts yet :L
Any help appreciated, thank you.

This is the Html:

```
<form id="surveyForm">
Favourite movie?
    <input type="text" id="favMov" onblur="return $formValidation()"/>
    <span id="errorStyle"></span>
</form>
```

This is the Js:

```
    function $formValidation(elem) {

        //gather the calling elements value
        var val = document.getElementById(elem.id).value;
        //Just for testing - alert(val.length);
        //if the length value of the text field is blank - show error
        if (val == "") {
            document.getElementById("errorStyle").style.borderColor = "red";
            return false
        } else {
            //if they are not blank remove error text
            document.getElementById("errorStyle").style.borderColor = "green";

        }
    }
```

You can find a fiddle sample here:

http://jsfiddle.net/a45gn9w4/

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) Please use this service :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a45gn9w4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the submit of your form and call the function formValidation()

Then you can actually get those elements and validate if it is correct or not.

This is the html:

```
<form id="surveyForm" method="post" action="some_url_to_post">
    <label id="">Favourite movie?<span id="error" class="noErrorHappen">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" id="favMov" name="favMov">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="validator" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is the js:

```
var error = document.getElementById("error");

var form = document.forms.surveyForm,
    elem = form.elements;


function formValidation() {
    if(!elem.favMov.value){
        alert('please input text.');
        elem.favMov.focus();
        error.className = "errorHappen";
        return false;
    } else {
        error.className = "noErrorHappen";
        return true;
    }
}



form.onsubmit = formValidation;
```

This is the CSS:

```
.errorHappen {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
.noErrorHappen {
  display: none;
}
#error {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean by that :/

Comment: I edited the answer for more clarity, with an example you can copy and paste it in jsfiddle

Comment: I also edited the question for clarity too, so the that reads does not have to go to snapshots hope it helps :)